# i tried searching repeat until loops and i only found repeat statement until condition

Tags: lua, repeat, until-loop

how do I make a successful repeat and until loop? what did i do wrong in my code?
I did

```
repeat
move forward()
until(tick{2}

)
```

I tried

```
repeat
move forward()
until{2}

)
```

here's the actual result:
the character moved sideways only 1 space once not one space every 2 seconds.
here's what i was expecting:
the character moved sideways every 2 seconds

Comment: What game engine this script is designed for?  Set the corresponding tag on your question please.

Comment: `until{2}` will never terminate since tables are always truthy. We don't know what `tick` does and `move forward` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Lua `repeat` has a simple Syntax

```
-- repeat.lua
local i = 0 -- Lets work with this
local s = 1 -- Stepsize that can be changed

repeat
  if i == 0 then -- Output only at Start
    print('Start to Repeat')
  end

  i = i + s -- Increment

-- Doing something with i
  print(type(i), i, i * i, i + i, ((i * i + i) / 2), math.rad(i))

  if i > 200 then -- Break Condition
    print('Repeat stopped') -- Output before break
    break -- Leave the Loop here
  end

  s = s + i -- Increment the Stepsize

until i == 420 -- Never reached (Because of Break Condition)
```

Output of above

```
Start to Repeat
number  1   1   2   1   0.017453292519943
number  3   9   6   6   0.05235987755983
number  8   64  16  36  0.13962634015955
number  21  441 42  231 0.36651914291881
number  55  3025    110 1540    0.95993108859688
number  144 20736   288 10440   2.5132741228718
number  377 142129  754 71253   6.5798912800186
Repeat stopped
```

OK - Simpliest is to have a Function to repeat that returns either `true` or `false` than...

```
-- Stopping when Function returns true
repeat until function_that_returns_false_or_true()
```

Or

```
-- Stopping when function returns false
repeat until not function_that_returns_false_or_true()
```